# Why do i get duplicates of characters as I type when using node.js socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

this is my first time posting so please be sincere. I watched an Introduction to Node.js by Ryan Dahl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I. So I tried implementing the chat example as he has implemented in this video but mine duplicates each charecter that I type in from the client side console and reflect to other clients before I hit enter. Am using windows CMD for both server(**C:>node P:\chat.js**) and client(**telnet localhost 3000**). **Below is my code:**

```
net = require('net');
var sockets = [];
var s = net.Server(function(socket){

sockets.push(socket);

socket.on('data', function(d){

console.log("Just received data");

for(var i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++)
{
    if(sockets[i] == socket) continue;

    sockets[i].write(d);
}
});
socket.on('end',function(){

var i = sockets.indexOf(socket);

sockets.splice(i,1);

});

});

s.listen(3000);
```

Comment: show your client.js please

Comment: What you've got there works fine on a Linux system. So I doubt the code is the problem.

Comment: Louis thanks for your comment, I tried it on Linux and it works just fine.